# How to fry Italian sausages without producing so much smoke?

Tags: frying, sausages

I just fried 2 Italian sausages on a non-stick pan, which created enough smoke to briefly set off my smoke alarm.

The sausages are delicious, but how can I do this next time without producing so much smoke?

Comment: What did you fry them in?

Comment: @Chad.  Can't speak for the poster, but I have found that people like a few small paragraphs, even for a short answer.  Something about a three line text block just looks small, insignificant, and uninviting.

Comment: @Emmet - do you have a vent hood with a fan?  If so, does the fan help?

Comment: @Chad It wasn't clear who answered first when I accepted. Both answers were "answered 2 hours ago" and answers with the same number of votes are sorted randomly.

Comment: @Emmett - Ah, that does make it tricky.  For future reference, you can hover your mouse over the time (e.g. "yesterday") and it will show the exact time.  Thanks for writing back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use less heat.

It's not clear if you used any fat here. If you do, you have to be aware of the [smoke point](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/collectedinfo/oilsmokepoints.htm) of whatever oil you're using.

By turning down the heat you'll decrease the amount of fat you are burning, and turning into smoke. If you want to still get a nice crisp exterior you can briefly sear your sausages on high heat prior to fully cooking. Although, his might be irrelevant since you don't really get good sears with a non-stick surface.

Answer (score 6):

A lower heat.

You should be able to fry them at a comfortable heat (e.g. medium rather than medium high).

Also, if you add any oil to the pan, use a higher smoking point oil like canola. If you have a splatter screen, that can help to trap some of the oil rather than letting it fall back into the pan and burning.

Comment: an experiment...